# iAd will not display after uploading app to store

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, iad

When I test my app on my device, from Xcode, the iAd works, but when I have uploaded it to the App Store and test it on a friend's iPhone, it's just white!

Here is my code:

.h:

```
@interface pinpongViewController : UIViewController {


ADBannerView *banner; 

}


@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;



@end
```

.m:

```
@synthesize banner, bannerIsVisible;



-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)abanner {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, 50.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}


@end
```

Comment: Where are you creating your **ADBannerView**, and how are you adding it to the **UIViewController**? Also, is this the only banner in your entire application? If not, keep in mind you have to share a single instance between multiple views.

Comment: The banner is an IBOutlet, so I presume it's simply being created from the xib.

Comment: Several things you could check as @pat mentioned, if you have enabled iAd network for you app? If so, wait for a few days, let people download and use your app, then the iAds will show up. My case is, ads showed up after 30+ downloads 4 business days after my release.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229207/how-long-do-iad-apps-take-to-start-generating-impressions

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the iAd network for your app, before submitting to the app store? It is required to enable iAd network(in iTunes connect) or else only a white screen appears! Hope this helps.