# App is approve and in app store, icon image is not present

Tags: ios, ipad, icons, iad

I just had a free version of my app approved by the app store. I downloaded it on a non-developer device and the app icon is not present. All you see is the default white background with the guides for design. I checked my xcode project and the images are there, and when testing the device the icon shows up like it should. How did Apple miss this?

Also, iAd is not working at all. When testing it it says it is working correctly. When downloading from the app store it is not present at all. I have wifi, added the framework.

While typing this:
The icon is not showing up on the ipad, but works on the iphone.
iAd does not work on either.

I am guessing i am missing a certain size for the icon on the iPad.
As far as iAd, does it take a time period to start working? (My first app with iAd).

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Ok, I am missing icon sizes: 72x72 and 144x144.  I figured that out. Now if i can get iAd squared away.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment states that you've noticed you're missing 72x72 and 144x144. Here's the complete list of sizes that you should include (for iOS 6/7 and iPhone/iPad support):

29x29, 40x40, 50x50*, 57x57, 58x58, 60x60, 72x72, 76x76, 80x80, 100x100**, 114x114, 120x120, 144x144, 152x152, 512x512, 1024x1024

*50x50 iOS icon should actually be 48x48 on a 50x50 canvas. A 1 pixel outline is stripped from the icon in this case.

**100x100 iOS icon should actually be 96x96 on a 100x100 canvas. A 2 pixel outline is stripped from the icon in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the iAd problem, did you turn on iAds within iTunes Connect?

If you select your app from under 'Manage Your Apps', there is a blue button on the right hand side to 'Set Up iAd App Network'... did you go within here and enable iAds?

You can only enable/disable iAds as part of a new app binary submission, so you will need to submit a new binary in order to enable iAds.

Comment: iAd is turned on in iTunes connect. I checked all the financals.

Comment: I also found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229207/how-long-do-iad-apps-take-to-start-generating-impressions

Comment: Seems like a possibility. If you click on your app in iTunes Connect and see 'Set Up iAd App Network' then they're not enabled, if you see 'Manage iAd App Network' then they are enabled.

Comment: It was worth a shot, sorry I couldn't help further!

Comment: Well, 3 days later iAd is working perfect. I guess it just takes a bit for the ads to start popping up. Thanks for the insight