# adBannerView not showing in approved app

Tags: ios, adbannerview, iad

My app has been approved, and its now on the App Store it runs correctly and in the simulator the adBanners work as they are supposed to, but the problem is that in my published app there are no ads so i first tough that it must be because of the number of downloads but as i kept looking on the internet i found that it could be because of the contract in iTunes connect, but I've filled all the contracts.

My question is : "Do I need a minimum of downloads for the ads to appear or my implementation of the iAd workbench in my app is incorrect?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my app was approved, it took 3 weeks to show the banner correctly. During these weeks, I sent 2 emails to Apple Developer Program to check the status. They said If you could see the test banners on your device, it's not your problem. Just be patient.

Also, the amount of ads you got somewhat depends on the number of downloads. According to most developers, the more your app is downloaded, the higher the fill rate. But even if your download is 0, you should get at least some of the ads. If you don't get any ads, it's not the main reason.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: well i liked your answer but the fact is that it appeared on the App Store December the 30th so... I'll wait

Comment: I highly recommend you to send a email to iAd helpdesk. Also check the iAd if the status of your app is "active"

Comment: where can i check the status, i was looking but i never found such thing

Comment: (Couldn't post image right now...)Go to itunesconnect.apple.com, click on iAd(the forth icon in the first column), in the opened page, scroll down and click on "View your ad reports", and there you go!On the bottom you can see the list of your apps(if you can't see your app in the list, send an email to Apple, they will add it for you ). There's a light behind each of your app. If the light is green, it means ads on this app are working perfectly. If the light is yellow, it means this app is still pending.

Comment: found it thank you, it says "Live Ads", is that the way it should look?

Comment: What's the fill rate? If it's "Live Ads", it's fine. If you are not able to see the ads on your own devices but you still get impressions(check the app list), that's normal. Apple does so to prevent developers from fraud clicks

Comment: My app also has been released on 30th December and is still not receiving iAds... @reojased are you receiving ads now?

Answer (score 0):

No it just takes times for ads to show up in the app, could take up to a week but usually only takes a few days.

See this post for reference: [How long do iAd apps take to start generating impressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229207/how-long-do-iad-apps-take-to-start-generating-impressions)